# How to stop/isolate while(true){} in Java( C# and NodeJS)

Tags: java, c#, node.js

Assume that I have some code that because of a bug sometimes does

```
while(true){/*...*/}
```

It is in a third part library that I have no source code for.

In Java I can isolate it in a CompletableFuture. But since the 3th party code is not cooperating Timeout will not work on The future. Stopping a custom Thread pool also does not work. I tested that with a literal 'while true...'

Java's Thread.stop() is deprecated, but works more or less.

How should I stop such never returning non cooperating code after a certain time in Java?  Should I use a process?

Same question for C# and NodeJS.

Comment: Using a process seems most reasonable. Does the foreign code react on Thread interruption? This will throw interrup exception when thread calls sleep or is in a blocking io

Comment: The infamous `while(true)`.. Not sure why this still appears in production code

Comment: In C# you can try isolating it in an Application Domain.

Answer (score 1):

In c# context you have `Thread.Abort()` which will try to intercept on each managed code execution step and stop threads execution. Although, this option is not recommended since it can cause thread to be left in corrupted state while it is being killed, unmanaged resources hanging and other unwanted behavior.

A better idea would be to bound execution of this 3rd party code in a different process and end process with your provided time out. That incurs a greater performance penalty but you do not risk of any resources or locks hanging.